# How to deal with URI and Uri in java?

Tags: java, android, uri, type-conversion

I'm using a library that requires me to pass an `Uri` object as parameter.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
File file = new File(someFileDir, "test.pdf");
someObject.someFunction(file.toURI());
```

Note that the `File` object has the function `toURI()`. It returns an `URI` object.

Now my problem is that the function I call needs a `Uri` parameter, but it's complaining that I passed a `URI` object.

Aren't these things exactly the same? How can I output an `Uri` object? Or how do I convert `URI` to `Uri`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deal with it as a string, It's easier.

Comment: Yup, was easier than I though it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use Uri.Builder() to create a Uri !

Answer (score 2):

For you information, URI seem to come from the JAVA language (java.net.URI), and Uri, from the Android SDK specificaly (android.net.Uri). So I would advise you to use the "Uri" class...

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that this was an Android related problem. At least now I know why there are two of them.